# Change date format in nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have a list of index symbols and data as follows:

```
lis={{"^AEX", {{{2015, 1, 2}, {425.89, 428.09, 420.35, 422.28}}, {{2015, 1, 5}, {420.06, 424.58, 410.49, 410.94}}}},
{"^AFLI", {{{2015, 1,2}, {5563.4, 5587.7, 5535., 5586.3}}, {{2015, 1, 5}, {5586.3,5622.1, 5578.9, 5598.3}}}}}
```

I would like to change the data format to mySQL format "Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day".

If I use

```
DateString[lis[[1,2,1,1]], {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]
```

I get {2015-1-2} for the first entry but I do not know how to change all dates in the whole list.

Does anyone have a hint? Thanks

Comment: `MapAt[DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] &, lis, {All, 
  2, All, 1}]` is one way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `lis`...

```
newlis=MapAt[DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] &, lis, {All, 2, All, 1}]

(*
{{"^AEX", {{"2015-01-02", {425.89, 428.09, 420.35, 422.28}}, 
           {"2015-01-05", {420.06, 424.58, 410.49, 410.94}}}},
 {"^AFLI", {{"2015-01-02", {5563.4, 5587.7, 5535., 5586.3}}, 
            {"2015-01-05", {5586.3, 5622.1, 5578.9, 5598.3}}}}}
*)
```

If you need date in its own list, brace the map function:

```
{DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]}

(*
{{"^AEX", {{{"2015-01-02"}, {425.89, 428.09, 420.35, 422.28}}, 
           {{"2015-01-05"}, {420.06, 424.58, 410.49, 410.94}}}},
 {"^AFLI", {{{"2015-01-02"}, {5563.4, 5587.7, 5535., 5586.3}}, 
            {{"2015-01-05"}, {5586.3, 5622.1, 5578.9, 5598.3}}}}}
*)
```